# Jquery using the click function to just reference buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have this line in my script to reference any button click on my page

```
        $("input").click(function() {
      alert ("clicked") ; 
        but_id = (this.id);
        });
```

It will then work on any input element but I cant seem to reference just a button . I thought this would work but is does not

```
        $("input :button").click(function() {
```

can anyone offer any advice please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jquery supports a wide range of selectors. You can select all input buttons and submits by its type by doing:

```
$('input[type=button], input[type=submit]')
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a submit button, you can do something like this:

```
$('input[type=submit]').click( function(e){

} );
```

JQuery is awesome because it has full CSS3 selector support, regardless of whether or not the browser does.

This means you're allowed to use things like [first-child](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) and [nth-child](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) and your javascript will work, even in older browsers.

For more detail, take a look at [attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) or the [JQuery selector API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).